# Redirect Cloud Page when string is in url

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, landing-page, redirect

I’m looking to redirect a user from a Marketing Cloud Landing Page if a certain string such as "/eb=1&eb_timestamp=" is contained in the url.

I’m struggling with this and would really appreciate any help from the community on what I need to add to my page.

Scenario, users arrives to url https://landing.landingpage.com/eb=1&eb_timestamp= and the string has been concatenated to the main url, as a result they get redirected to http://landing.landingpage.com/home

I’m struggling with this and would really appreciate any help from the community on what I need to add to my page.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. You want to test whether the query string provided is "?eb=1&eb_timestamp=" or the url ends with "/eb=1&eb_timestamp=" (broken url). I'm presuming the "/" is a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach it this way:

```ampscript
%%[

var @dc
var @pageURL
var @debug

set @debug = 1
set @dc = QueryParameter("dc")
set @pageURL = RequestParameter('PAGEURL')

if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("<br>pageURL: ", @pageURL))
  output(concat("<br>dc: ", @dc))
  output(concat("<br>index: ", indexOf(@pageURL, "dc_timestamp")))
endif

if @dc == "1" and indexOf(@pageURL, "dc_timestamp") > 0 then

  if @debug == 1 then
    output(concat("<br>redirecting..."))
  else
    redirect("https://ampscript.guide")
  endif

endif

]%%
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this is great